# How can i replace content under a specific URL using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dotnetnuke

I have a question about updating and replacing content in SQl.

Let's say i have database name AXY, and inside AXY database i have Tables folder and under Tables folder i have .dbo.TabUrls.

And below is how i replace my content :

```
UPDATE AXY..HtmlText
SET Content = REPLACE(CAST(Content AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 'OLDCONTENT', 'NEWCONTENT')  
WHERE Content LIKE '%OLDCONTENT%'
```

.dbo.TabUrls has the field [Url] which stores all the URL.
And i want to change content only in the page with the [Url]='/flupke/%'

What's the query must I run?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `UPDATE AXY.dbo.TabUrls SET Content = REPLACE(Content, 'OLDCONTENT', 'NEWCONTENT') 
WHERE Content LIKE '%OLDCONTENT%'`

Comment: `And i want to change content only in the page with the [Url]='/flupke/%'`. can you give some example from `Content` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(CONTENT VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341107/flupke/somethnigelse')
,('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341107/flupke123/somethnigelse')
,('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341107/somethingflupke/somethnigelse')
,('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341107/nothing/somethnigelse')
,('http://stackoverflow.com/flupke/33341107/flupke/somethnigelse')

DECLARE @PATTERN_TO_FIND  VARCHAR(20) = '%flupke%'
DECLARE @NEW_CONTENT VARCHAR(20) = 'NewContent'

SELECT 
    CONTENT
    ,IsMatch = PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND,CONTENT)
    ,ToReplace = SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(CONTENT, PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND, CONTENT),LEN(CONTENT)),1,PATINDEX('%/%',SUBSTRING(CONTENT, PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND, CONTENT),LEN(CONTENT)))-1)
    ,ReplacedContent = 

    CASE WHEN PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND,CONTENT) > 0 
         THEN REPLACE(CONTENT,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(CONTENT, PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND, CONTENT),LEN(CONTENT)),1,PATINDEX('%/%',SUBSTRING(CONTENT, PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND, CONTENT),LEN(CONTENT)))-1),@NEW_CONTENT)
         ELSE CONTENT
    END
FROM @T
```

[image]

As can be figure out that, only those URL's where '%flupke%' are getting replaced. 
So, in my opinion, the REPLACE function should be

```
REPLACE(CONTENT,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(CONTENT, PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND, CONTENT),LEN(CONTENT)),1,PATINDEX('%/%',SUBSTRING(CONTENT, PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND, CONTENT),LEN(CONTENT)))-1),@NEW_CONTENT)
```

And your update query should be

```
UPDATE AXY..HtmlText
SET Content = REPLACE(CONTENT,SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(CONTENT, PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND, CONTENT),LEN(CONTENT)),1,PATINDEX('%/%',SUBSTRING(CONTENT, PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND, CONTENT),LEN(CONTENT)))-1),@NEW_CONTENT) 
WHERE PATINDEX(@PATTERN_TO_FIND,CONTENT) > 0
```

Let me know if the query worked as per my understanding of your question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE AXY.dbo.TabUrls 
SET Content = 'NEWCONTENT' 
WHERE Content LIKE '%OLDCONTENT%' 
AND URL LIKE '/flupke/%'
```